# is there any possibility to present an finance report in tableau? (like a balance sheet or excel sheet format)

Tags: excel, tableau-api, finance

I am working on a financial report now.there is an excel format available. i have to repeat the same in tableau. is it possible? or try o suggest some other BI tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Tableau, based on what I know it should be possible. My company use Qlikview to present financial report.

[image: Qlik]

http://www.qlik.com/

Comment: okay. will it be able to display the viz like a balance sheet? and also is there any incremental refresh option?

Comment: Do you mean T-Format? For incremental reload please look at this link https://community.qlik.com/thread/48633

Answer (score 0):

Is your data source in a fixed row/column structure?  Tableau does not have any predefined formatting for financial statements in my experience, unless an ERP vendor has built something  custom.  You would have to create your own through 'groups' and calculated fields.

Comment: yes there is an predefined format.which i have to replicate in tableau.

Comment: ok - then yeah you would have to accomplish this through grouping and custom fields